# Failed to install Octave. Error: you have held broken packages

Tags: 14.04, apt, dependencies, octave

Here is the error I got while trying to install `octave`:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:octave/stable
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install octave
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 octave : Depends: libarpack2 (>= 2.1) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libcholmod2.1.2 but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: liboctave3 (= 4.0.2-1ubuntu5~octave~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: default-jre-headless but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried many ways to install `octave`, but they have failed.

Comment: Check if `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` gives any output

Comment: no it does not give any output..

Comment: Ok. The question is closed as duplicate. My facebook id is http://fb.com/arun.alpy